# beginning HTML: src tag not working properly?

Tags: html

I am working through Quentin Watt's new HTML5/CSS3 tutorials.

The last few tutorials have dealt with inserting image, audio, and video files.  In each and every case the browser recognizes my attributes, like height, width, controls, etc., but doesn't actually display the file.

Code:

```
<!-- tutorial 10 -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ntf-8"/>
        <title> tutorial 10 - video tag </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video width="640" height="360" controls>
            <source src="HowTo.BackLever.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> If you can see this you need to update your browser>
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am confident my path is correct, its all local.  The files in question are in the same directory as the source code for the page.

I have tried with both Chrome and Firefox and I can't figure out why the browsers won't display the files.

I have researched the issue and have found nothing (helpful) on this site or through Google.

Comment: The video is in the same directory as the html file?

Comment: yes they are in the same directory

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Ive tried both Chrome and Firefox (Windows 7).

Comment: What is actually displayed?

Comment: A black box of the appropriate dimensions a play button and a mute button.  Hitting play doesn't really have an affect on anything.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image file is on your webroot (probably www or htdocs), then reference that in your src.

Comment: Could you explain what this means?  I feel like my issue could have something to do with the files not being public or something like that.

Comment: The file(s) are just in a folder on my desktop, the same folder that the HTML doc is in.

Comment: could be the path, double check.

Comment: I tried figuring out what you meant but every hit is basically this private company, Webroot.

Answer (score 0):

You sure the video file path is correct? Is there a `.` between HowTo and BackLever in the filename? Check the exact name of file and the path.

Comment: Yes I put it there.  But the point is the same thing is happening regardless of the file type.

Comment: Like the image filled is mapped out with height and width matching the attributes I assign, the video file shows controls and is mapped out with the pixels I assign, but there is no video or image.

Comment: It's not a matter of the file type. If you go to properties of the video file stored on your computer, you need to reference it with the exact file name. You should create a folder on your desktop and put your files inside that to keep things a bit more uniform.

Comment: Yeah I know its not the file type, my point was that its not the path in this particular code.  I am having the same problem on multiple pages with different file formats.  Its like my code is correct, my path is correct but something is blocking the file.  Like a browser or OS default security setting or something.

Comment: What browser are you using? When you launch the file are you seeing the default text "If you can see this you need to update"?

Comment: I have tried both Chrome and Firefox.  No, that is kind of my point.  It doesn't display that text.  It displays "a video" just no content.  Like there controls and the appropriate pixels are blacked out for where the video would play...but no video plays.

Comment: As suggested above, have you tried dragging and dropping the video from your desktop into the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the exact same code running under same conditions as yours (video and html on same folder).

It's working. You should check for the video name, as you know it should be exactly the same as in the HTML code.

```
        <!-- tutorial 10 -->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ntf-8"/>
<title> tutorial 10 - video tag </title>
</head>
<body>
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
<source src="HowTo.BackLever.mp4" type="video/mp4">
If you can see this you need to update your browser>
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd suggest using a easier name for the video file just to make sure. ;)

Comment: Yeah appreciated.  But its not just on this page when I use a video file.  I am having the same problem with other pages and other file formats.

Comment: Right click the HTML page and go to View Page Source. Right-Click on the file URL, Open in New Tab and see if the browser runs it.

Comment: So yeah, its like the code is working.  The file name is correct, etc.  But no content...just recognized video tag, attributes etc.  Same for an image or audio file.

Comment: After viewing page source and clicking the URL it just get some like run time message but no video plays.  Its like it lists the file path in grey at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I tried right clicking the URL and opening the link in a new tab and it couldn't find the file.

Comment: Well then it didn't find the file. Drag and drop the file on your browser and see if it plays.

Comment: Yeah, so that is cool, didn't know you can do that.  Dragging and dropping worked, the file played.

Comment: Has to be incorrect reference. Go to properties and copy and paste the filename here for us.

Comment: So, the browser CAN run the file. But it's not recognizing it trough the HTML code. That's weird...

Comment: That is strange. Try to rename the video file to video and change the html to reflect.

Comment: I will but I have messed with different file names and including / excluding the mp4 extension.  It doesnt make a difference.

Comment: Ha I am thinking of just moving on.  I mean clearly I understand the lesson from the tutorial.  But at the same time, you would like the thing to actually work...

Comment: Ok this gotta be a stupid question but you are saving the HTML file before refreshing the browser, right?

Comment: What does this mean: "Make sure your image file is on your webroot (probably www or htdocs), then reference that in your src."  What is my webroot?

Comment: Your webroot would be the folder where your server is located. That if you were using a server (apache, for example). But you are using a single HTML file, so the 'webroot' they are mentioning would be simply the folder your HTML file is at.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely the file path. Try renaming your video and use the new name.

```
src="my_video.mp4"
```

I've also seen people following this video with their file extensions hidden so then they actually add the extension to their file name, making the real src for the video "my_video.mp4.mp4". If it works with a double extension, then you know that is your problem.

You can also make sure you are using the correct file type by right clicking on your video and looking at "properties" in Windows or "get info" on OSX. Please see the image below. I could only find a mov file on my mac this morning, but you need to make sure your video is an mp4.

[info for files on mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X3Zc.png)

[video properties in windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg3H4.png)

Something else you did differently is added a greater sign here. I don't think that's the problem, but I just thought it was worth the mention.

```
If you can see this you need to update your browser>
```